# Изолировать код

Tags: теги, php, вёрстка

И снова я со своим WSYIWYG редактором. Я тут подумал, что если просто так вывести запись, содержащую открывающие теги без закрывающих, или закрывающие без открывающих, то они могут поломать всю разметку сайта. Например: </div></div></div></div></div> - и вот всё поехало. Как можно от этого обезопаситься? мне почему-то в голову приходят iframe, но они показывают контент из других файлов...

Comment: берите любой парсер html (для питона - [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), для php, java есть свои аналоги). И пропускаете результат пользовательского ввода через него. Распарсив, он исправит явные проблемы.

Comment: iframe можно управлять и из js. вот простой пример http://jsfiddle.net/X7BnU/, другое дело xss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему-то никто не сказал самый очевидный способ: написать функцию, которая автоматически закрывает теги. Таких полно уже готовых в интернете, например вот: [link text](http://artkiev.com/blog/php-tags-close.htm)
Что самое интересное, я не нашёл ни одной функции, которая бы открывала неоткрытые. Что ж, немного переделываем функцию по ссылке, и получаем требуемое. Надеюсь кому-то пригодится:

```
function open_close_tags($content){
    $position=0;
    $open_tags=array();
    $ignored_tags=array('br', 'hr', 'img');//теги для игнорирования
    while(($position=strpos($content, '<', $position)) !== false){
        if(preg_match("|^<(/?)([a-z\d]+)\b[^>]*>|i", substr($content, $position), $match)){//забираем все теги из контента
            $tag=strtolower($match[2]);
            if(!in_array($tag, $ignored_tags)){//игнорируем все одиночные теги
                if(!isset($open_tags[$tag])){
                    $open_tags[$tag]=0;
                }
                if(isset($match[1]) AND $match[1] == ''){//тег открыт
                    $open_tags[$tag]++;
                }
                if(isset($match[1]) AND $match[1] == '/')//тег закрыт
                {
                    $open_tags[$tag]--;
                }
            }
            $position += strlen($match[0]);
        }else{
            $position++;
        }
    }

    foreach($open_tags as $tag => $count){
        if($count>0){
            $content.=str_repeat("</{$tag}>", $count);//закрываем незакрытые
        }
        if($count<0){
            $content=str_repeat("<{$tag}>", -$count).$content;//открываем неоткрытые
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

заменять символы на html сущности (e.g. '<' (знак "меньше чем") преобразуется в '&lt;'), но с такой постановкой вопроса лучше мне кажется вначале как следует мат часть освоить (js как я понимаю), а потом уже что-то писать.

Comment: Я же указал, что данные идут из WSYIWYG редактора. Это значит, что пользователь может использовать разрешённые теги (особенно если html код редактирует), и это значит, что все теги мне надо отобразить как теги, а не преобразовывать их в сущности.